# Solr Systemd Watchdog

Tags: solr, systemd

Is there a way to run a background thread in solr that would run a systemd watchdog (ie sd_notify) to make systemd aware of solr's status?

[This library](https://github.com/faljse/SDNotify) seems like a reasonable way to implement sd_notify in java.

I can't find much information about a way to hook into SOLR's startup to kick off a background thread that would handle the sd_notify calls.

Comment: Seems [like plugins should receive a call to init() when they're being loaded](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Plugin_Initialization), and you might be able to piggyback as a eventlistener if you need to add the plugin to an actual function?